# Using ng-repeat directive on a <tr> element

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I use Rails for backend and angularjs for frontend.
In my angularjs controller I have:

```
app.controller('ReportsInsurerPaymentsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.insurerPayments = [];
  $scope.commissions = [];
  $scope.insurers = [];

  $scope.getInsurerPayments = function () {
    $http.get('/reports/insurer_payments.json').success(function (data) {
      $scope.insurerPayments = data.payments;
      $scope.commissions = data.commissions;
      $scope.insurers = data.insurers
    })
  };

  $scope.getInsurerPayments();
}]);
```

My Rails controller gives me json with 3 arrays: `insurerPayments`, `commissions` and `insurers`. In my view I want to show my `insurers`, `commissions` and `insurerPayments` in a table, so I do something like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <tr>
    <th>Insurers</th>
    <th>Commissions</th>
    <th>Insurer Payments</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="insurer in insurers">
    <td>{{insurer.name}}</td>
    <td>{{}}</td>
    <td>{{}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So, how can I do that, using ng-repeat for different arrays? Thank ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use $index for comparsion

```
  <tr ng-repeat="insurer in insurers">
    <td>{{insurer.name}}</td>
    <td>{{ commissions[$index] }}</td>
    <td>{{ insurerPayments[$index] }}</td>
  </tr>
```